# Computing minimum distance between observations within groups

Tags: r, dplyr

In the dataset below, how could I create a new column `min.diff` that reports, for a given observation `x`, the minimum distance between `x` and any other observation `y` within its group (identified by the `group` column)? I would like to measure the distance between `x` and `y` by `abs(x-y)`.

```
    set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(
  group = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'),
  value = sample(1:10, 8, replace = T)
)
```

Expected output:

```
  group value min.diff
1     A     9   2
2     A     4   3
3     A     7   2
4     B     1   1
5     B     2   1
6     C     7   4
7     C     2   1
8     C     3   1
```

I prefer a solution using `dplyr`.
The only way that I have in my mind is to extend the dataframe by adding more rows to get each possible pair within groups, calculating distances and then filtering out the smallest value in each group. Is there a more compact way?

Comment: @RonakShah please check the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map_dbl` to subtract current value with all other values and select the minimum from it for each `group`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(min.diff = map_dbl(row_number(), ~min(abs(value[-.x] - value[.x]))))
       

#  group value min.diff
#  <chr> <int>    <dbl>
#1 A         9        2
#2 A         4        3
#3 A         7        2
#4 B         1        1
#5 B         2        1
#6 C         7        4
#7 C         2        1
#8 C         3        1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `combn` to do the pairwise difference between 'value', get the `min` of the `abs`olute values

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% 
          mutate(new = min(abs(combn(value, 2, FUN = function(x) x[1] - x[2]))))
```

If we want to get the `min`imum between a given element i.e. `first` from the rest

```
 df1 <- df %>%
            mutate(new = min(abs(value[-1] - first(value))))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think does not quite do what I want - this would take the minimum distance between any two observations within each group - so that ```new``` is constant within groups. On the other hand, I want the minimum distance between a GIVEN element and any other one within its group

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito perhaps the update works for you

Comment: It still doesn't work - If you check my updated dataset, results are still wrong. On the last row, for instance, we should have value = 1 since in group C, we have that |3-2| = 1

Answer (score 0):

If the order doesn't matter...

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  arrange(group, value) %>% #Order ascending by value, within each group
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(min.diff = case_when(lag(group) == group & lead(group) == group ~ min(c(abs(value - lag(value)), abs(value - lead(value))), na.rm = T), #If the "group" for the previous and next entry are the same as the current group, take the smallest of the two differences
                              lag(group) == group ~ abs(value - lag(value)), #Otherwise, if only the previous entry's group is the same as the current one, take the difference from the previous
                              lead(group) == group ~ abs(value - lead(value)) #Otherwise, if only the next entry's group is the same as the current one, take the difference from the next
                              )
         ) %>%
  ungroup()

  #    group value min.diff
  #    <chr> <int>    <int>
  #  1 A         4        3
  #  2 A         7        2
  #  3 A         9        2
  #  4 B         1        1
  #  5 B         2        1
  #  6 C         2        1
  #  7 C         3        1
  #  8 C         7        4
```

If the order is important, you could add in an index and rearrange it after, like so:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(index = row_number()) %>% #create the index
  arrange(group, value) %>%
  mutate(min.diff = case_when(lag(group) == group & lead(group) == group ~ min(c(abs(value - lag(value)), abs(value - lead(value))), na.rm = T),
                              lag(group) == group ~ abs(value - lag(value)),
                              lead(group) == group ~ abs(value - lead(value))
                              )
         ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(group, index) %>% #rearrange by the index
  select(-index) #remove the index


#   group value min.diff
#   <chr> <int>    <int>
# 1 A         9        2
# 2 A         4        3
# 3 A         7        2
# 4 B         1        1
# 5 B         2        1
# 6 C         7        4
# 7 C         2        1
# 8 C         3        1
```